# Audio recoding voice quality is not good

Tags: iphone

```
// Init audio with record capability
audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
{
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];   
}
else
{
    NSNumber *formatObject;

    switch (recordEncoding) {
        case (ENC_AAC): 
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ALAC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless];
            break;
        case (ENC_IMA4):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
            break;
        case (ENC_ILBC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatiLBC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ULAW):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatULaw];
            break;
        default:
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
    }

    [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
}
```

Comment: the code is working but the voice quality is not up to mark please help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try recording with the settings from this question:

[iphone-peakPowerForChannel function in AVAudioRecorder doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191617/iphone-peakpowerforchannel-function-in-avaudiorecorder-doesnt-work)

The settings used there seem a bit different from the ones you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Use this recoed setting for AVAudioRecorder....

```
recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

Its work, i have done it...

Regards

Comment: it work but my question is that after recording is done the whole apps sound is very low

Comment: ya, DUDE.. But check about recording Dictionary which you had create earlier.. And i had post only recording Dictionary.. After that you need to use dictionnary in AVAudioRecorder..

Comment: ya dear i already add the dict in avrecorder but the problem same as please help if you have any idea thank

Comment: why you use encode setting..? why you set initnumberofcapacity to NSDictionary..? just try NSDictionary which i had wrote earlier.. Thanx..

Comment: hi jagdish encoding is used to encode differnt type of formate and i did try nsdictionary without init capacity but i feel no differ then priveos one. thank

Comment: ohhh.. i had used dictionary only for .wav file which i had done it earlier.. But you want more formats like abc.mp3 , abc.wav , abc.aif , abc.abc... Thanx..